# no such file or directory 'package.json' while using npm start in mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I use the npm start command this error shows up:

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path /Users/kratichoudhary/package.json

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kratichoudhary/package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

Answer (score 5):

Usually this issue happens whenever you try to `npm start` in the wrong directory.
Make sure your terminal is pointing to the same directory where your `package.json` file is and then run the command.

If the problem is still not solved, please share some more details

Answer (score 0):

I have had also this problem and i know that this problem was defined after changing path "CMD".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit registry settings. You need to leave only the default files in this path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor"